# select values from several tables using get method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-3.0

```
$pilot = $this->Pilots->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Cars']
     ???
]);
```

Entity Pilots "has many" cars, so does cars "has many" models and last but not least models has many brands.

I want to get all the cars , it's models and brands that bellong to pilot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$pilot = $this->Pilots->get($id, [
    'contain' => ['Cars.Models.Brands]
]);
```

[CakePHP 3.x Eager Loading Assocations Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations)

EDIT:  Should have just went with the dot notation the first time, my mistake.  Please see my edited example above.

Comment: Error: Unsupported operand types File .../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/EagerLoader.php 
Line: 292

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
Not working, I'm getting an object serialized but no Models or Brands values...